# How to fix an aborted firmware upgrade on Cisco SLM2048

Tags: cisco, switch, firmware

There is a Cisco SLM2048 switch and the last firmware upgrade aborted, now the switch doesn't work anymore. I can't access the switch. The only evidence is a blinking system LED. As the switch doesn't have a serial console, is there a way of fixing the firmware and thus the device?

Comment: Did you try to access (http or telnet) switch via default ip 192.168.1.254 ?

Comment: no there isn't any activity on networklayer